# no integration graph view in eclipse sts 4?

Tags: xml, eclipse, spring-integration, spring-tool-suite

Don't even have the option of creating spring bean config files anymore, a slew of features just gone from the transition to 3.9 to 4? Seems like they sacrificed quite a bit on the eclipse end for that IDE agnosticism if this is the case...

Comment: why do you think my assumptions are wrong? the comment you link to implies they've cut features "go back to 3.9...it still has all the old features included.". I've scoured the net already for any information on this, including the comment you linked to, what does come up is repeated ad nauseam and almost all attributed to Martin himself only acknowledging the new features and portability of the new implementation. As the comment you've linked to states there is no spring project nature anymore nor is there any migration protocol besides 'use 3.9 if it's not in 4.0'

Comment: what about my question do you require clarification on exactly? my question is clearly asking someone who knows what's going on if the integration graph has been removed in sts 4 in favor of a universal tooling product aimed at multiple code editors. Anyone who uses the product should attest to their own experience on the matter. you respond with your own conjectures that my assumption about the feature being removed being 'probably' wrong based on nothing but a link that doesn't at all support your opinion.

Comment: I don't think your assumptions are wrong or anything in that direction. The docs of Spring Tools 4 contain a section about missing STS3 features in Spring Tools 4 here: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/STS3-Features - and please feel free to file an issue if anything is missing or not clear enough there. And again, if you would like to see specific pieces of the STS3 tooling coming back into the Spring Tools 4, please feel free to raise an enhancement request, those are more than welcome.

Comment: Again, I am not saying at all that missing the graphical views for Spring Integration definitions is wrong or anything like that. I explained that we haven't re-implemented them for Spring Tools 4 in the first place and are therefore not included in Spring Tools 4 yet - but we listen carefully to the community and are happy to work on features that people raise enhancement requests for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Spring Tools 4 do not contain any support for Spring XML configuration files anymore, we removed that support completely from the tooling. Spring Tools 4 focuses on Spring Boot and using annotations to configure your Spring application.

As a side effect of that, the specific support for Spring Integration got removed, too. That is the reason you don't see any graphical representation of Spring Integration XML files anymore.

There is an option to install the old STS3 components as an add-on into the Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse (you can find that on the Eclipse marketplace). That way, you get both (the old and the new tools) in the same IDE. This is not meant as a permanent solution, but to allow for a smooth migration to the new tools in case something is missing or you desperately need a specific piece of the old tooling.

In those cases, I would recommend to raise an enhancement request for the new tooling at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues in order to get important features into the new tooling before the add-on will reach its EOL (in mid 2019). We very much love to hear from you what you are missing and what should be added to the new tooling. It will probably not come back in the same way (since the news tools are re-written from scratch using a totally different tooling architecture), but understanding what is missing and why you would like to get a specific piece back would be awesome.

Comment: Also, the STS graph was only useful for a single XML configuration file - it could not handle multiple files, nor Java or DSL configuration of SI flows. We have moved to a runtime graph that represents the runtime component graph (JSON), which can be rendered - see [the README for this sample app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/applications/file-split-ftp) for an example.

Comment: Even not supporting multiple files STS graph was very useful - even to discuss the flow with the busines users, PoCs, etc). I really missed this feature in this version and to be honest my first impression was that your are trying to get rid of Spring Integration itself as a framework, or at least making it less visible somehow. I hope I'm wrong, big fan and user talking here.

Comment: The missing support for visualizing Spring Integration graphs in Spring Tools 4 is NOT AT ALL based on de-emphasizing specific projects or in indication that we would like to get rid of something - NOT AT ALL. Do not interpret it that way. Since the Spring Tools 4 is based on a completely new toolig architecture, we couldn't just port everything over from the old tooling. Again, if you really like the graphical representation and would like to get them into Spring Tools 4, please raise an enhancement request at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues, it would be more than welcome.

Comment: Phew! Thanks for the heads up. I'll raise an enhancement request shortly. Before a leave, what is your opinion about the excessive usage of "builder" design pattern for everything? What about the code readability? Have you ever had to change a complex message flow using DSL instead of XML using Spring Integration?  Gary, please leave a comment if possible. Thank you! Martin, I understand your hard work with this new version. I wish I could help you some how!

Comment: I would recommend to ask the question about the design patterns and Spring Integration best practices in a separate question.

Comment: And if you would like to get involved with the tooling, it is fully open-source - and we very much welcome new contributors... :-)

Comment: >`Gary, please leave a comment if possible`. @AndréDiniz, don't make comments on old answers - especially not my answers because I don't get any notification of such comments, so that could lead you to believe I am ignoring you. As Martin said; ask a new question instead. We are not saying XML doesn't still have a place, just that the tooling team didn't have the resources to port it; and many modern Spring Integration apps use Boot auto configuration and the DSL and the legacy graph only supports XML config (and only a single file). Take a look at the runtime flow rendering; it's more useful.

Comment: No worries, Gary.

Comment: Also see https://ordina-jworks.github.io/architecture/2018/01/27/Visualizing-your-Spring-Integration-components-and-flows.html