# Spring Integration IDE

Tags: spring-integration

I remember seeing the palette in Spring Tool Suite (long time back) to design the Spring Integration work flow which I cannot find in Spring Tool Suite 4.x. Can someone tell me if it is available as a separate add-on or how do I enable it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the answer to this question and associated comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52564074/no-integration-graph-view-in-eclipse-sts-4).

It is not currently available in STS 4.x, although, as stated by Martin Lippert there, the 3.9.x tooling can still be installed.

Bear in mind that it was limited to a single XML configuration file and many modern Spring Integration applications use Spring Boot auto-configuration and the Java DSL which cannot be rendered by the graph; Spring Integration now provides a runtime graph that can be rendered by a number of tools and works with any configuration technology.

Comment: Thanks Gary. This helps