# Does STS supports spring integration plugin for view the integration flow?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, spring-integration, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

is there eclipse/sts plugin for Spring Integration flow GUI (designer)? if yes which version of STS has that?

I have installed latest STS 4-4.2.2.RELEASE, not seeing support for Spring Integration flows, not able to see the graphical representation of the flow. How we can spring integration projects to see the integration flow in STS (View the design of the integration flow.)

the applicationcontext.xml file is representation in a clear text,  not like a graphical interface.

I have tried to find the plugins, but I couldn't for STS.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53951800/spring-integration-ide/53953705#53953705) and the one it links to.

Comment: Graphical diagram-like editors for Spring Integration, Spring Batch, and Spring Webflow, is there solution in STS and Eclipse?

Comment: See Martin Lippert's answer referenced by the linked answer. `There is an option to install the old STS3 components as an add-on into the Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse (you can find that on the Eclipse marketplace). `.

Comment: Thank you Martin & Gary! I am installing it now, I will update the status here.

Comment: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-3-add-aka-spring-tool-suite-3 (did not work in STS4)

Comment: So comment on Martin's answer. He is the STS lead.

Comment: if the install of the STS3 add-on pack doesn't work, please file an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues and we will take it from there. Some more details about what exactly doesn't work (which versions, the install steps you took, what went wrong etc.) would be awesome in there.